# How to use "Style" properly with "ListPointPlot3D"?

Tags: plotting, graphics, graphics3d, style

Using MMA 12.0 on a Windows 10 machine.

I am trying to plot a list of points in a 3D plot. Each point has a different weight which I want to show using different point sizes. The points are also in different clusters and I want to show that using different colors. Let's say maybe three or four different colors. The total number of points in a plot would be between fifteen and twenty but I may end up producing more than a thousand of these plots.

The best that I have figured out is to use "ListPointPlot3D" with "Style". But it seems like that I can only specify one specification using Style. I can do either the color or the point size. I can't do both.

For example,

```
ListPointPlot3D[{Style[{0, 0, 1}, Green], Style[{1, 0, 0}, Red]}]
```

works perfectly fine, as expected, and I get one green point and one red point.

[image]

I can specify the point size on either one and it works.

```
ListPointPlot3D[{Style[{0, 0, 1}, PointSize[0.1]], 
  Style[{1, 0, 0}, Red]}]
```

[image]

```
ListPointPlot3D[{Style[{0, 0, 1}, Green], 
  Style[{1, 0, 0}, PointSize[0.1]]}]
```

[image]

But when I try to specify both the color and the point size for a point, both specifications are ignored.

```
ListPointPlot3D[{Style[{0, 0, 1}, Green, PointSize[0.5]], 
  Style[{1, 0, 0}, Red]}]
```

gives me neither a green point nor a large point.

[image]

The documentation for [Style](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Style.html) says that

> Style[expr,spec1,spec2,...] allows the speci to be any list or sequence of the following:

But both, a sequence of specifications

```
Style[{0, 0, 1}, Green, PointSize[0.5]]
```

and a list of specifications

```
Style[{0, 0, 1}, {Green, PointSize[0.5]}]
```

fail.

How can I make this work? I hope this is not a bug or anything. Do I need to do something completely different?

One method that I can think of is

```
g1 = ListPointPlot3D[{Style[{0, 0, 1}, PointSize[0.05]], 
   Style[{1, 0, 0}, PointSize[0.03]]}, PlotStyle -> Green];
g2 = ListPointPlot3D[{Style[{0, 1, 1}, PointSize[0.02]], 
   Style[{0, 2, 0}, PointSize[0.04]]}, PlotStyle -> Red];
Show[g1, g2, PlotRange -> {{-1, 2}, {-1, 2}, {-1, 2}}]
```

[image]

This gives me what I want but feels inefficient and is probably slower. Is it? The code is longer, a bit uglier, and I have to manually figure out and specify the PlotRange because Show is not smart enough to figure out the optimal plot range. I would need to have 3-4 plots and then merge them into a single plot every time. Can this be done with a single ListPointPlot3D?

I have no great affinity for Style or even ListPointPlot3D. If there is a vastly superior (faster/more-efficient/easier-to-read/terse) method, then I wouldn't mind learning about it.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure this makes things quite as compact as you'd like but what about

```
points = {{0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 1}, {0, 2, 0}};
colors = {Green, Green, Red, Red};
size = {0.05, 0.03, 0.02, 0.04};

ListPointPlot3D[{#} & /@ points,
 PlotStyle -> ({#[[1]], PointSize[#[[2]]]} &) /@ Transpose[{colors, size}], 
 PlotRange -> {{-1, 2}, {-1, 2}, {-1, 2}}]
```

[image: 3D points]

Comment: +1 Oh good lord, I messed around with such a vector approach for a while but gave up where colors and size can be vectors. I couldn't get it to work. Didn't realize that PlotStyle can be a list of lists. I'll wait to see if any other answers are posted. This will make my overall code much smaller. Thanks!

Comment: Why do you have an anonymous function in the first argument, for `points`? Wouldn't just `ListPointPlot3D[points,...` work? Do we need the extra set of braces?

Comment: Try it.  I believe that the points need to be separated into separate lists otherwise just the first `PlotStyle` is used.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple graphics directives like the color and point size can be passed to `Style` by using `Directive`.  For example,

```
ListPointPlot3D[{
  Style[{{0, 0, 1}, {0, .1, 1}, {0, .2, 1}}, 
   Directive[Green, PointSize[0.02]]],

  Style[{{.2, 0, 1}, {.25, .1, 1}, {0.2, .2, 1}}, 
   Directive[Blue, PointSize[0.015]]],

  Style[{{.4, 0, 1}, {.45, .1, 1}, {0.4, .2, 1}}, 
   Directive[Red, PointSize[0.025]]]
  }]
```

[image]

Comment: +1 Ah, this is what I was missing. This wasn't obvious anywhere in the documentation or my search engine results. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at [`BubbleChart3D`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BubbleChart3D.html)

```
n = 20;

SeedRandom[1234]

points = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {n, 3}];

weights = RandomReal[{0.5, 1}, n];
```

Tailor the [`BubbleScale`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BubbleScale.html) and [`ColorFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ColorFunction.html) to taste

```
BubbleChart3D[
 Append @@@ Transpose[{points, weights}],
 BubbleScale -> "Diameter",
 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z, r},
   ColorData["Rainbow"][Norm[{x, y, z} - Mean[points]]]]]
```

[image]